# How to use window's keydown listener for keys Chrome uses as shortcuts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, addeventlistener, keydown

Strange problem I've come across running this code in Google Chrome:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    console.log(event)
})
```

While I see the log for some keys ("w", "a", "s", spacebar, "esc", for example) - other keys do not trigger this event: "d", "r", "l"

In fact, some of these letters (like "r") are a built-in shortcut in Chrome that cause some other event to fire, i.e a page refresh.

Interestingly, using `preventDefault` does not solve the problem:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(event)
})
```

Note that **in Firefox the original code (without `preventDefault`) works fine** - but not in Chrome.

Any idea how to solve this?

**Update**
Might be worth noting (though I'm not sure why this affects it) that when running this code from the file system, there is no problem on Chrome. But once this code is being served (i.e from `localhost`) then we run into the issue.

Comment: What are you talking about? `r` is not a built-in shortcut in Chrome (nor any of the other keys you list), otherwise people wouldn't be able to type or generally use the internet at all. However, `Ctrl+r` is a shortcut... are you trying to use key combinations like that? In that case, `event.preventDefault()` **will** disable the shortcut in Chrome as long as your page sees it.

Comment: @Herohtar maybe i should've been more specific - but clearly if you're in an input box/area these "default" events don't get triggered. But for whatever reason, I'm experiencing these unwanted shortcuts on any page **without** pressing `Ctrl`

Comment: no, no. please see the answer i've submitted. i am a fool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. Turns out I had an extension installed which was doing some whacky things with keybindings.

It's a good extension otherwise for productivity, but if anyone else is using it, watch out for this gotcha:

[Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
        console.log(e.keyCode);
    })
```

you can use  e or event..
if you keydown any key , you will get the specific keycode for that key.
then you can put any conditions like,

```
if(e.keyCode == 32){
   video.pause();
}
```

32 is the keycode of spacebar